# Vb.net 2010 failed to load database information

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I am very upset because I have being tired searching on net for this solution..
Every time this error occurs when i try to load data from my dataset to view on crystal report

I am using VS2010 Ultimate on 32-bit PC.

My codes are as follows :

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

        Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1()
        Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim MyCommand As New SqlCommand()
        Dim myDA As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim myDS As New DataSet1


        myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Projects 2014\sorry\sorry\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
        MyCommand.Connection = myConnection
        MyCommand.CommandText = "select Name from Customer"
        myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "Customer")
        rpt.SetDataSource(myDS)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: unless it is a secret, can you tell us what `this error` is?  is the SQL returning a valid dataset? will it display in something like a grid?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the above code so that for just confirmation, the data is also populated in datagridview.. but it can't populate in crystal report.. same error (failed to load database information)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Projects 2014\sorry\sorry\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select name from customer", myConnection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Projects 2014\sorry\sorry\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select name from customer", myConnection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
```

on windownForm `C#` ?

Comment: Why is there a question mark ? Isn't this supposed to be an answer ?